# Create view with Union give error in IBM i

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

HI I am trying to add one table data to another to create the needed data set. I am doing a UNION via the green screen STRSQL. This gives an error  message:     COLUMN LIST REQUIRED' 
in CPYF add, you don't have to do anything, whne the legnths and attibutes of each fields are the same.  but here not sure what to do.

```
                 create view astccdta.eoddetails as                                
                 SELECT LINTOT, ODORD#, ODSEQ#, ODLSTC, ODORDD, ODORDT, ODPRLC,    
                 ODPRT#, ODSHP#, ODNTU$, ODRQSD FROM astccdta.eoddetaila UNION     
                 SELECT LINTOT, OUORD#, OUSEQ#, OULSTC, OUORDD, OUORDT, OUPRLC,    
                 OUPRT#, OUSHP#, OUNTU$, OURQSD FROM astccdta.eoddetailh
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to specify a column list for your view.  Generally this is done like: `View_Name (Columns...)`

Comment: `in CPYF add, you don't have to do anything, whne the legnths and attibutes of each fields are the same.` Not true if the field names don't match. You do indeed have to 'do something' to make it work, i.e., *NOCHK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to try is to add the column lists:

```
create view astccdta.eoddetails(LINTOT, ODORD#, ODSEQ#, ODLSTC, ODORDD, ODORDT, ODPRLC, ODPRT#, ODSHP#, ODNTU$, ODRQSD)                            
      SELECT LINTOT, ODORD#, ODSEQ#, ODLSTC, ODORDD, ODORDT, ODPRLC,    
             ODPRT#, ODSHP#, ODNTU$, ODRQSD
      FROM astccdta.eoddetaila
      UNION     
      SELECT LINTOT, OUORD#, OUSEQ#, OULSTC, OUORDD, OUORDT, OUPRLC,    
             OUPRT#, OUSHP#, OUNTU$, OURQSD
      FROM astccdta.eoddetailh  ;
```

Perhaps this is required for STRSQL.

DB2 definitely accepts views without explicit column names.

EDIT:

You may also be able to do this:

```
create view astccdta.eoddetails as                            
      SELECT LINTOT, ODORD#, ODSEQ#, ODLSTC, ODORDD, ODORDT, ODPRLC,    
             ODPRT#, ODSHP#, ODNTU$, ODRQSD
      FROM astccdta.eoddetaila
      UNION     
      SELECT LINTOT, OUORD# as ODORD#, OUSEQ# as ODSEQ#, OULSTC as ODLSTC,
             OUORDD as ODORDD, OUORDT as ODORDT, OUPRLC as ODPRLC,    
             OUPRT# as ODPRT#, OUSHP# as ODSHP#, OUNTU$ as ODNTU$, OURQSD as ODRQSD
      FROM astccdta.eoddetailh  ;
```

Comment: I think it needs the column list because the column names are different between the two tables.  If the column names were the same then you would not have to specify them.

Comment: @ScottMildenberger . . . Normally, in a `union` query, the column names are taken from the first subquery.  I don't know why a union query would be sensitive to this.

Comment: I tested this and the complete error description has this as one of the possible reasons: "Corresponding columns of the subselects in a UNION, EXCEPT, or INTERSECT do not have the same name."  So it doesn't matter for the UNION but it does when creating a VIEW of it.

Comment: @ScottMildenberger . . . That is pretty convincing.  I don't know of any other database that behaves like this.

Comment: pretty sure I've addressed this a couple of times by replacing `Union` with `Union All`, although Union would ensure values are unique and Union All would allow for duplicates (not sure why that would work when Union does not though)